# beautifulsoup scrape realtime values

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

i am trying to scrape the currency rates for a personal project, i used css selector to get the class where the values are. There's a javascript providing those values on the website and it seems i am noot too connversant with the developers console, i checked it out and i could not see anything running in real time in the networks section. This is the code i wrote, so far, it brings out a long list of dashes. surprisingly, the dashes match the source code for those parts were the rates are supposed to show.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
r = requests.get("https://www.ig.com/en/forex/markets-forex")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
results = soup.findAll("span",attrs={"data-field": "CPT"})
for span in results:
    print(span.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Span-elements filling via JS, dynamic values. On start each span-element contains '-'.
You need js driver for wait to fill elements and then get values from spans.

With selenium:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
driver.get('https://www.ig.com/en/forex/markets-forex')

for elm in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span[data-field=CPT]"):
    print(elm, elm.text)
```

chromedriver download from https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

Also, [dryscrape](https://github.com/niklasb/dryscrape) + bs4, but dryscrape seems outdated. Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python)

Modified:

```py
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
driver.get('https://www.ig.com/en/forex/markets-forex')

time.sleep(2) # Maybe more or less, how much faster page load

for elm in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span[data-field=CPT]"):
    if elm.text:
        print(elm, elm.text)
```

or

```py
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
driver.get('https://www.ig.com/en/forex/markets-forex')

data = []
while not data:
    for elm in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span[data-field=CPT]"):
        if elm.text and elm.text != '-': # Maybe check on contains digit
            data.append(elm.text)
    time.sleep(1)
print(data)
```

Comment: this doesn' t bring out the value . This is what it shows <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="03cb3c86bb76aea8f5d00c135321a307", element="d6351af3-939e-4ad4-96e4-fc1cc6afe7f0")> -

Comment: Need time for load values, add sleep

```python
import time

#...

driver.get('https://www.ig.com/en/forex/markets-forex')
time.sleep(3)

#...
```

or check values in loop, example:

```python
data = list()
while not data:
    for elm in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span[data-field=CPT]"):
        if elm.text != '-':
            data.append(elm.text)
```

Comment: Second better with sleep
```python
import time

#...

data = list()
while not data:
    for elm in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span[data-field=CPT]"):
        if elm.text != '-':
            data.append(elm.text)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: You can edit and add this to your first answer for proper indentation. Comments don't have. I'll try it.

Comment: Done, from "Modified:"